# Fluent syntax for transforming futures

Tags: java, java-8, guava, future

I am using [Guava Futures](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html) to chain future invocations together. In particular I am using a composition of `Futures.transform(...)` and `Futures.transformAsync(...)`, but the resulting code is not really very readable. Is there a way to express the same thing in a more 'fluent' way?

Comment: can you show an example of what you mean by *not very readable*?

Answer (score 3):

<sub>@ChrisPovirk [mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44020510/fluent-syntax-for-transforming-futures#comment75084715_44026431) last month that a fluent wrapper was soon to appear in public Guava, well it's there now in 23.0-SNAPSHOT.</sub>

The new [`FluentFuture`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/107f311e182d4b8298a10093ae4c5c6bc02641ec/guava/src/com/google/common/util/concurrent/FluentFuture.java) class is annotated with `@Beta` so maybe even when Guava 23.0 is released it might still be subject to change.

Anyway, if you `git clone` Guava right now, you can do this:

```java
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
// WARNING: based on UNRELEASED version, this is just to get a glimpse of the future... (Future... get it?) :o)
FluentFuture<String> f =
        FluentFuture.from(immediateFuture("world"))
                .transform(name -> "Hello " + name, directExecutor())
                .transformAsync(input -> immediateFuture(input + "!"), executor);
System.out.println(f.get());
```

<sup>(which, amazingly, prints "Hello world!")</sup>

Comment: Guava 23 rc1 is released now!

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for fluent methods chaining like in JDK's `CompletableFuture`:

```
completableFuture
    .thenApply(f1)
    .thenApplyAsync(f2, executor)
```

then no, it's not possible using Guava's `ListenableFuture` and wrapping `transform`s is the way to go. *(Maybe inside Google they have some fluent wrapper? EDIT - you work for Google so you'd know ;))*

Having said that, you can:

- use some existing code to extend `ListenableFuture` with fluent methods (like in [this - rather niche - Github project called `fluent-futures`](https://github.com/mgodave/fluent-futures), but it uses old Guava <20 API),
- write your own wrapper with such methods (ex. based on `CompletableFuture` or `fluent-futures` API),
- stick to Guava API (at least it's what we do when we deal with `ListenableFuture` APIs),
- use some adapters and convert `ListenableFuture` to `CompletableFuture` and use its (fluent) API - ex. [future-converter](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/future-converter):

  ```
  import static net.javacrumbs.futureconverter.java8guava.FutureConverter.*;

  //...
  ListenableFuture<String> guavaListenableFuture = toListenableFuture(completable);
  //...
  CompletableFuture<String> completable = toCompletableFuture(listenable);
  ```

Comment: (We do have a fluent wrapper out for review right now, hopefully to be submitted within the next couple weeks. It will show up in public Guava then, as well.)

Comment: That'd be great, can't wait for that!